# Cocoa - Pause a method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods

How would I go ahead about pausing a method without freezing the UI, and then continuing the process when told?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: NSOperation. I'd give you more information, but I'm currently learning how to do it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2009/tn2109.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a way to interrupt execution of an arbitrary method and to then resume it later.

You can break your method into multiple pieces that represent the units of work that you want to be able to pause between.  You can then use timers (either `NSTimer`s or `[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` for a specific pause interval.

More information on what you're trying to do might allow for some more specifically useful suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to prevent the UI from stopping and eg. timers too. This is more or less the whole reason why we have run loops (well, thats not really true but in your case it is).

Just insert this into your function and everything will work:

```
while(pauseFunction)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1f]];
}
```

Remark: Everything scheduled with the runloop keeps running, this is the UI, timers, networking etc. pp.

Comment: @Kevin: Its something that has to evaluate to true if you want to pause the function and that needs to evaluate back to false once the function should unpause.

Comment: What is the NSRunLoop for? Does that prevent the UI from freezing?

Comment: @Kevin: Read the documentation about NSRunLoop, its too much for a comment and there are so many use cases for it, that you should read it anyway to be prepared for the future.

Comment: Ok I have entered your code into my app, but the UI still does not work. I am able to move it but I can't even click a single button.